# Accessing SQLite in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to create a SQLite database, working within Jupyter Notebook.

However, when I run the command to create the database, I'm presented with the error **'No module named 'sqlite''.** (See image for full command and response).

Checking the 'Environments' page of Anaconda Navigator, I can see that **'sqlite' is actually listed as an installed package.**

What am I missing out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use `sqlalchemy` which takes away a lot of pain. You can install it like this in a Jupyter notebook cell (note the !)

```
!pip install sqlalchemy
```

Then your code would be as follows.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///first_db.sqlite')
connection = engine.connect()
```